Unknown light source in viewport when camera projection is orthogonal
I'm using Godot/Redot for my game development but so far this happens when camera projection is orthogonal, there's unknown light following the viewport when the camera is moving.
Here's the example

And here's the camera inspector and lighting


Solved:
The mistake in the mesh and camera. There's a transparent mesh to recreate a roof for the room. Still, the camera moves using transform-origin and makes the transparent mesh get in the way of the camera movement path, so the shadows are culling incorrectly.

Are you using a physically based material that simulates fresnel reflection at glancing angles? This sometimes doesn't handle orthographic projection correctly, leading to weird highlights as objects approach the edges of the screen.

This is a silly mistake from me, I tried to create a transparent mesh to recreate a roof for the room. Since the movement of the camera is using transform-origin the transparent mesh gets in the way and hits the camera movement path so the shadow is culling incorrectly

Neat! Want to document that in an Answer below?
